# Save PFPointer in a variable

Tags: pointers, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I've been having some trouble trying to save an objectId on a variable and then using this variable for doing a query with a pointer.

I have the following code:

```
  var currentObject : PFObject?
var objId : NSString?




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if let object = currentObject? {
        subjectName.text = object["name"] as? String
        roomLabel.text = object["room"] as? String
        teacherLabel.text = object["teacher"] as? String


    }

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Calendar")
    query.whereKey("subjectId", equalTo: objId)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            for object in objects {
                NSLog("%@", object.objectId)
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }







    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

The code itself is displaying the content of a certain object on some labels.
I want to save the object id in the objId variable.
There seems to be no errors but when I run the code I get the following error:

error = "pointer field subjectId needs a pointer value";

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subjectId` is a pointer but the query is testing it against a string.  (its not a surprising mistake because the variable is named misleadingly... with `Id` as the suffix, we expect it to be a string.  `subjectPointer` would be a better suffix).

To fix, make the id into a pointer using [objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:).  Use `objId` as the objectId, and the class name is the name of the table that contains the object with that id (hopefully your table is named something like "Subject").

**EDIT** - Here's my best shot at swift (not my language either)

```
let pointer = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"Subject" objectId:objId)
query.whereKey("subjectId", equalTo:pointer)
```

I used "Subject" as the table name, but you must replace that with the real name of the table that contains the object whose id is objId.

Comment: Could you please give me an example on how to do this? I read the documentation about  objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId and I don't get it due to the fact that it's written in Objective C.

Comment: @OmarDlhz - gave it my best shot.